# connection string in c#

Tags: c#, connection-string

I have to access data from an MS Access DB stored in a central server.What should be the connection string in c# for it? Currently the connection string for the access database stored in my local machine is as follows:

```
string ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\GAURASI\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\IMPACT\PACEDB.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=PACE@impact";
```

Comment: Is there any connection error? What is the problem exactly?

Comment: use UNC path (i.e: \\files\db\acess.db)

Comment: Does this website help: http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Answer (score -2):

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
Data Source=\\server\share\folder\myAccessFile.accdb;
```

Refer [this](https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/)